# Indexing Android

Tags: android, indexing

My problem is I have around 1000+ records in an Android App

```
string field1;
string field2;
string field3;
string field4;
//...
```

I want to search in this set of records and get the best results on two fields (`field1` and `field2`).

Currently I read each record and `compare()` (string compare) with the text i want to search so that takes a long time.

What is the best method to perform search?

1. Store each records in SQLite DB and do "select query where like"
2. Hash-Mapped
3. ? any other suggestions?

Or may be create an Index of the records and do search.

Comment: what is a "best" result? Is it a perfect match?

Comment: for e.g., Given string : "Fox got over today etc.. etc.." and search string is "today", then it should return true as string is present.

Comment: This information should be in the question! You may want to read about regex, pattern and matcher.

Comment: A quick example can be found here http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search for *not* exact matches, I would try to make an `ArrayList` of `MyAppRecord` where

```
public class MyAppRecord {
    private String record;
    private int deviance;
}
```

and get for each record the deviance of the String you want to find with:

```
public static int getLevenshteinDistance (String s, String t) {
    if (s == null || t == null) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Strings must not be null");
    }    
    int n = s.length(); // length of s
    int m = t.length(); // length of t

    if (n == 0) {
      return m;
    } else if (m == 0) {
      return n;
    }

    int p[] = new int[n+1]; //'previous' cost array, horizontally
    int d[] = new int[n+1]; // cost array, horizontally
    int _d[]; //placeholder to assist in swapping p and d

    // indexes into strings s and t
    int i; // iterates through s
    int j; // iterates through t

    char t_j; // jth character of t

    int cost; // cost

    for (i = 0; i<=n; i++) {
       p[i] = i;
    }

    for (j = 1; j<=m; j++) {
       t_j = t.charAt(j-1);
       d[0] = j;

       for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
          cost = s.charAt(i-1)==t_j ? 0 : 1;
          // minimum of cell to the left+1, to the top+1, diagonally left and up +cost                         
          d[i] = Math.min(Math.min(d[i-1]+1, p[i]+1),  p[i-1]+cost);  
       }

       // copy current distance counts to 'previous row' distance counts
       _d = p;
       p = d;
       d = _d;
    }

    // our last action in the above loop was to switch d and p, so p now
    // actually has the most recent cost counts
    return p[n];
  }
}
```

save it to your `MyAppRecord`-object and finally sort your `ArrayList` by the `deviance` of its `MyAppRecord`-objects.

Note that this could take some time, depending on your set of records. And NOTE that there is no way of telling wether dogA or dogB is on a certain position in your list by searching for dog.

Read up on the Levensthein distance to get a feeling on how it works. You may get the idea of sorting out strings that are possibly to long/short to get a distance that is okay for a threshold you may have.

It is also possible to copy "good enough" results to a different `ArrayList`.

Comment: I somehow feel that you have given the wrong function "getLevenshteinDistance" as I am not able to relate it to my query.

Comment: There was nothing to Hide. Anyways, I found a different way to get the data filtered by some specific sql queries.

Comment: "hiding information" is a friendly way of telling you that your question is not precise.